# Firebase data loading everytime i set a state

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build an app with category list. I wanted to make the selected category bigger and give it a bold color. But every time i set state, it refreshes the screen and then it sets the state. Can i stop it from refreshing every time i set a state?

this is my code

This is my Future

```
Future getCategories() async{
    var firestore = Firestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await firestore.collection("category").getDocuments();
    return querySnapshot.documents;
  }
```

and this is my future builder

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: getCategories(),
    builder: (_, snapshot){
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Container(
          child: Text('Loading'),
        );
      }else return ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children:
          List.generate(snapshot.data.length, (int index) =>
              InkWell(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(snapshot.data[index].data["category"],
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: currentCategory == snapshot.data[index].data["category"] ? sActive : sNotActive,
                          color: currentCategory == snapshot.data[index].data["category"] ? active : notActive,)
                      ,),
                  ),
                onTap: () {
                  String selectedCategory = snapshot.data[index].data["category"];
                  setState(() {
                    currentCategory = selectedCategory;
                    print(selectedCategory);
                  });
                },
              )));
    })
```

Comment: The only `setState` call in the code you shared should only trigger when you tap the `InkWell`, not each time it is rendered. Are you sure this is the one causing the loop you see? Can you may add some logging to show that that is really what's happening, and then include the updated code and its output in the question?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes you are right its refreshig when i set state (when i tap the inkwell)or change tab

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem in that case. If you don't want it to refresh on a tap, why do you call `setState()` in the `onTap`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen becuase i want to show the catagory list under it but i dont want it to refresh

Answer (score 1):

When you use `setState()` the entire widget will rebuild and subsequently the `FutureBuilder` which will call the `getCategories()` method again.

You can call the `getCategories()` method (without awaiting it) in the `initState()` and save the future in a property of the state class and then use this property in the future builder instead of `getCategories()`.

Another solution could be to move the `ListView()` in a separate widget, so you can rebuild only the `ListView` when you select an item and call `setState`.

Anyway you can use for example the [BLoC pattern](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4074597-getting-started-with-the-bloc-pattern) to manage the state, in this way you don't need to rebuild the entire widget.

Comment: the list view is the one refreshing in the first place